# How can i change classname condition with map?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to change a classname condition in a React map.
I need to open different modals but they are in map and each one have a different state name but {item.value} is not working.

This is my code:

```
<div
className={`${{item.value} ? "" : "hidden"} fixed inset-0 z-10 bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-95`}>
```

Comment: try <div className={${item.value ? "" : "hidden"}  you have put an extra "{" there making it a object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting `item.value` in an object and then implicit cast it to boolean to evaluate it.
It should return almost always `true` without regardind of the value in `item.value`.

Try this:

```
<div
className={`${item.value ? "" : "hidden"} fixed inset-0 z-10 bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-95`}>
```